# Movie clip about Robots, Goddess and a Kid

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I saw this movie clip a few years ago, maybe around 2015. It is in color. It is animated but I think it's not use the same animation style of common Japan anime. It has no subtitle or any dialogue when I saw it. So, it could be a trailer too.

Here is some detail about the movie clip.

There is this main character ( I think), the Kid, standing on a cliff and see some spaceships battle. Something then launched from the spaceship and the Kid start chasing it using his flying motorcycle.

After he got there, it turn out it is a safety pod with a goddess inside ( she wears a divine like robe and she floats), then they are attacked by the previous space ship. It shoots laser and sent robot swarms to destroy them. The Kid grab the goddess and start to run away.

After some chasing through caves and canyons one of the robot successfully destroy the flying motorcycle. After the Kid recover from the explosion, there is this big bad robot with giant weapon trying to chop him off. Before the weapon touch the kid, the robot get attacked by the goddess using sort of laser. Then, many more of the spaceships appear from the sky above and the clip ended.

Comment: If you only saw a clip, are you sure it's a movie or could it be a show? (if it's not a trailer)

Comment: I'm sure it is an animated movie like anime. I'm not seeing it from the very beginning. It could be from an anime episode or anything else.

Comment: It's a strecth, but a girl in a robe saved by a guy with a flying motorcycle, robots and lasers _could_ be _Castle in the Sky_... If you remember the events' order all wrong, that is :) just in case, see if this compilation remembers you of anything?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YGLS_lAPco

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the one I looking for. I really remember the goddess. It is.different from the link above.

Comment: @Shota do you remember colors, such as goddess garments (while?), robots, motorcycle, spaceships? Was Kid blond?

Comment: Can you tell me why you call her a goddess? Does she have powers?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi Ithink the color of the goddess robe is light blue and white with something (floating) around it. The robot is metallic color and the spaceship is kinda long and grey or silver in color

Comment: @HyperNym She can floats and maybe using magic or tech, i do no know. And I think when she attack the robot she use laser like lightning, different from common laser beam

Comment: Could you be thinking of Uchuu Senkan Yamato 2199? It's not exactly as you describe, but It's the only one I could think of

Comment: @rapturus No, it's not Uchuu Senkan Yamato 2199